# Javafx tableview checkbox to hide unwanted rows?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm trying to do some reports by hiding some rows from a tableview (I made in scenebuilder) by using a checkbox. If the object from tableview doesn't have in the column a specific String, it becomes invisible. example: By clicking the checkbox, hide all rows that dont have the exact value "Barcelona" in table_adress. I tried to do this, but I keep complicating myself. Any ideas?

***the function***

```
@FXML
     void CakeRequestsFromBarcelona(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        for(Object cake:table.getItems()) {
            for (TableColumn column : table.getColumns()) {
                //not sure how to write it
            }
        }
    }
```

***initialize***

```
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, Integer> table_ID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, String> table_adress;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, String> table_design;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, String> table_flavour;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, String> table_model;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, String> table_name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<CakeRequest, String> table_phonenumber;
    @FXML
    private TableView<CakeRequest> table;

public void initialize(){
        //cakeRequest
        table_ID.setCellValueFactory(
                p-> new SimpleIntegerProperty(p.getValue().getID()).asObject()
        );
        table_name.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getOwnerName())
        );
        table_adress.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getOwnerAddress())
        );
        table_phonenumber.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getPhoneNumber())
        );
        table_flavour.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getFlavour())
        );
        table_design.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getDesign())
        );
        table_model.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getModel())
        );
}
```

***CakeRequest***

```
public class CakeRequest implements Identifiable<Integer>, Serializable{
    private int ID;
    private String OwnerName;
    private String OwnerAddress;
    private String PhoneNumber;
    private String Model;
    private String Flavour;
    private String Design;
```

Comment: I advise following [Java naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) for code posted online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`FilteredList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) and change the predicate when the check box is checked/unchecked:

```
private ObservableList<CakeRequest> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private FilteredList<CakeRequest> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, request -> true);

public void initialize(){
    // existing code...
    table.setItems(filteredData);
}

@FXML
void cakeRequestsFromBarcelona(ActionEvent event)  {
    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        filteredData.setPredicate(request -> request.getOwnerAddress().contains("Barcelona"));
    } else {
        filteredData.setPredicate(request -> true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When i type table.setItems(filteredData), my table doesnt wanna update (i have a button that adds records into the table). I've looked online and also saw your other responses to similar problems and i tried to change it to table.setItems(data) so it can copy the objects added by the button (as far as i understood, it will share the same list) and then the filtereddata comes in. When i do this, it works, but after i check the button (changed to checkbox.isSelected()) nothing happens. atleast no error, but still. Any ideas?

Comment: @HyperOni Post a [mre] in your original question. You should set the items for the table to `filteredData` and make any changes (e.g. adding new values) to the original `data` list (not to `filteredData`).

Comment: Thank you! did a quick test and now its working. I didnt know that i must add into the original data. Thank you for this and your other answers! <3